# Phone numbers in web pages & privacy

Tags: html, privacy

I think I may already know the answer to this, but here goes.

I have a resume website I am creating, and the owner wants his contact information to be displayed on the page (understandably). My question is, how can I display this information to the user while still maintaining a sense of anonymity for my client? My first thought was to use images with bogus alt text, but using crowd-sourcing, I am looking for a potentially better solution. ;)

I want to thwart all possible phishing attempts, and the information to be displayed will be address, phone number, full name, email address, and web address.

Any help from the SOers is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about providing a contact form, rather than firm contact details, that way the contact is all going through a single medium. clients can still get in touch and personal details aren't spilled out onto the web. you could then think about adding a captcha to the form to prevent abuse from spam bots and the likes

any other approach (images with dodgy alt text or insertion via javascript) limit accessibility and so could cut out a portion of people who could be potentially interested in contacting the person

Comment: Thanks for the input! This is definitely the type of thing I was looking for. I may consider the contact form, but the main avenue of communication with this person will probably be through phone. Although, any contact where the website is the origin kind of points to email most of the time. The more I dwell on it the more I think this may be the best way to go! Thanks!

Comment: no problem :) if you added a field to the form for the interested party's phone number then they could be contacted back by phone. this limits potential abuse and allows for most contact to continue over the phone. that way it is just the first stage of communication that is conducted via the website